# Массив как аргумент функции

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Можно ли как то в функцию в качестве аргумента передать массив элементов и использовать его в запросе `SELECT`?

Например (псевдо-код):

```
function get_by_list(IDS массив numeric) return таблица_типа_Х pipelined is
begin
    for rw in(
        select что-то
        from таблица 
        WHERE ID in IDS;
    ) loop
        pipe row (rw);
    end loop;
end get_by_list;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так реализовать:

```sql
create or replace type num_list_type as table of number;
/ 
create type item_row as object (id number, item varchar2(32));
/
create type items_type as table of item_row;
/
-- тестовая таблица
create table items as select level as id, 'item no ' || level as item 
from dual connect by level<=7;
/
create or replace function getbyList(num_list num_list_type) return items_type pipelined is
begin
    for one in (
        select item_row(id, item) item 
        from items where id in (select * from table(num_list))
    ) loop
        pipe row(one.item); 
    end loop;
    return;
end getByList;
/
select t.* from table(getbyList(num_list_type(1,5))) t 
union all 
select count(1), ' total items'  from items
;
```

Вывод:

```
        ID ITEM                           
---------- --------------------------------
         1 item no 1                       
         5 item no 5                       
         7  total items
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать доп. функцию для преобразования CSV строки в таблицу:

```
create or replace type admin.strtable as table of varchar2(1000);
/

create or replace
function admin.str2tbl ( p_str in varchar2 ) return strtable
as
  l_str long default p_str || ',';
  l_n number;
    l_data strtable := strtable();
begin
  loop
    l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
    exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
    l_data.extend;
    l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
    l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
  end loop;
  return l_data;
end;
/
```

Тест:

```
SQL> select * from x;

         I
----------
        11
        22
        33
        44

4 rows selected.

SQL> select * from x where i in (select * from TABLE(admin.str2tbl('11,33')));

         I
----------
        11
        33

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Интересно было как раз, могу ли я передать под-запрос как аргумент функции, но сейчас стал думать что это что то не совсем правильное ...